# The time gap between the two instants, one before and one after 12:00 noon, when the angle between the hour hand and the minute hand is 66°

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

> **Question:** The time gap between the two instants, one before and one after $12:00$ noon, when the angle between the hour hand and the minute hand is $66^°$ , is
> $1.~~~~ 12 ~\text{min}.$
> $2.~~~~ 16~\text{min}.$
> $3.~~~~ 18 ~\text{min}.$
>  $4.~~~~ 24 ~\text{min}.$

**My thought:** We know that at $12:00$ noon, both the hour and the minute hand are at position $0^°$. 
Also after $x$ hours of time, the hour hand travels $x / 12$ rotations around the clock. So after $x$ minutes, it travels $x / (60 \cdot 12) = x / 720$.
After $x$ minutes of time, the minute hand travels $x / 60$ rotations around the clock.

Now how to proceed the further ? Please help.

Comment: Is the answer 24 minutes

Comment: There is a formula for such problems....angle difference is |30h - 5.5m| = Angle difference..h is the hours and m the minutes

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment by giving answer? @Mathslover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hour hand travels $360^\circ$ in $12$ hours, or $720$ minutes.  That is $\frac 12^\circ$ per minute.  The minute hand travels $360^\circ$ in $60$ minutes or $6^\circ$ per minute, so the minute hand gains $\frac {11}2$ degrees/minute.  To gain $66^\circ$ therefore takes $12$ minutes.  Similarly, going backwards, the minutes hand loses $66^\circ$ in $12$ minutes, so the times are $24$ minutes apart.

Comment: very nice approach. Thanks for the quick response.